# calculating decimal power of 10

Tags: python, modulus, exponential

I need some help with this calculation :

```
10**7342345.54334 % m
```

I am calculating it in python but that says *Result too large*

```
pow(10,7342345.54334,m)
```

Can not be used because all parameters must be integers. If I convert this decimal value to integer then the answer changes.

Comment: Well the largest `float` you can have in Python is `1.7976931348623157e+308`, so this isn't going to happen.

Comment: Sounds like someone doesn't want to do their arithmetics!

Comment: You were probably given this problem precisely because it can't be done the easy way.

Comment: its happening. @jonrsharpe

Answer (score 5):

Hint: Make use of the equivalence of the following expressions

[image: expression 1]

and

[image: expression 2]

For further details, see [Modular exponentiation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Modular_exponentiation) in Wikipedia.

Answer (score 2):

10<sup>7342345.54334</sup> is equal to 10<sup>7342345</sup> times 10<sup>0.54334</sup>. Now can you do it?

Comment: @BHATIRSHAD: I said "times", not "plus".